# Why is crontab giving me a permission error message when I copy my backup?

Tags: shell-script, permissions

I use a PuTTY session to copy my nightly backups to another location.  I log in as the `root` user and change directories to `/store/BackupLocation` which holds backups from the last 100 days.  I can then run:

`bash /bin/ScriptThatCopiesBackup.sh`

This script copies my backups from `/store/BackupLocation` to another directory `/store/BackupArchive`

This all works perfectly, but I can't seem to schedule this script to run automatically in crontab.  Instead I get the following permission error everyday:

```
/bin/bash: /bin/ScriptThatCopiesBackup.sh :Permission denied
```

**My question is, why am I recieving this error message even though everything is done by root? And what can I do to resolve this?**

Here are the permissions for my script:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 213 June 19 2013 ScriptThatCopiesBackup.sh
```

Here are my crontab settings:

```
30 16 * * * /bin/ScriptThatCopiesBackup.sh
```

Comment: Have you tried **temporarily** doing `chmod 777 /bin/ScriptThatCopiesBackup.sh` and rebooting to see if it works?

Comment: `777` is probably a bad idea; I'd suggest `u+x` to add the executable bit only to the file's owner.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that your script is not set to be executable.  `chmod u+x /bin/ScriptThatCopiesBackup.sh` will make the script runnable by its owner (in this case, `root`).

Comment: Well, the problem is that, when the OP runs the script manually, he says **`bash `** *`scriptname`*, but the command in the `crontab` entry is just *`scriptname`* … … … … … AND that the script is not set to be executable.

Comment: You're not wrong about the confluence of two problems.

Comment: I added what you suggested to crontab, but it still didn't work.  However I am no longer getting ther permission error emails.

Comment: It was not a suggestion of something to add to the cron table, but rather a suggestion of a command to run _in situ_ to resolve the problem.  The fact that you're no longer getting error emails indicates that the script is now working.

Comment: First, thank you for taking the time to help me. But I really don't think the script is working. Because when I check my Archive directory the latest backups are missing.

Comment: Check the mail for the user whose cron table the script is on for the script's output.  Or add logging to the cron table entry (`... 2>&1 > /path/to/script.log`) and review what you see.  Also, it's possible the script isn't setting its location correctly; try prefixing `cd /store/BackupLocation; ` to the cron table entry or revising the script to set the working directory explicitly rather than assuming its PWD is the correct place.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem could be that you are editing the wrong `crontab` file. (Even though you said you are doing everything from `root`). Try editing the `crontab` file with `crontab -u root`.

It is also possible that your script is not executable. `chmod +x /path/to/yourscript.sh`should make it executable.

Comment: `root` should never not have access to anything that's not experiencing hardware failures.